# Filter numeric values from a column of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the below. I am trying to extract only numeric values from all the columns in a list, whether it is on the right, left or middle of any characters. If the column value doesnot have numeric value, impute 0 instead of Nan

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['1', 3, "1", "cad -2", 3, 4.876, np.nan], 
    'B': ['116', 'CAD -2.6399', 'CAD -3', '$-', '$5%', 'A', '-1.2 2']
})
df
```

I tried the below code but it is giving NAN for row no 4 for variable "B"

```
l = ["A", "B"]
for columns in l:
    if df[columns].dtype == 'object':
        df[columns] = df[columns].astype('str').str.extract("([-+]?\d*\.\d+|[-+]?\d*\\d+)").astype(float)
df
```

I want my output to look like below:

```
A      B
1     116 
3     -2.6399 
1     -3 
-2    0 
3     5 
4.876 0
NaN   -1.2
```

Comment: What should happen if dataframes have different number of elements?

Comment: It should not do anything for other columns. For example, if the dataframe looks like this    ``` df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['$-', "cad -2"], 'B': ['116', 'CAD -2.6399'], 'C': ['$-', "cad -2"]}) df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 3, 4],'B': ['116', 'CAD -2.6399', np.nan], 'C': [1, 3, 4]})``` and I want to extract numeric values only from columns B and C (instead of all the columns in a dataframe).

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this :

```
mask_nulls_data = df.isnull()

for column in df.columns:
    if df[column].dtype == 'object':
        df[column] = df[column].astype('str').str.extract("([-+]?\d*\.\d+|[-+]?\d*\\d+)").astype(float)

#Only put zeros where extract method filled by NaN 
mask_nulls_string = df.isnull() & ~mask_nulls_data
df[mask_nulls_string] = 0
```

Comment: This code doesnot work if we want to extract numeric values from a particular column(instead of all the columns in a dataframe). In that case it gives the below error "TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value" error when I tried to extract numeric values from column B and C of both the dataframes by looping in the below dataframe.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['$-',  "cad -2"], 'B': ['116', 'CAD -2.6399'], 'C': ['$-',  "cad -2"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 3, 4],'B': ['116', 'CAD -2.6399', np.nan], 'C': [1, 3, 4]})

Comment: here is my code:
`l2 =[df1, df2]
l1 = ["B", "C"]
for files in l2:
    mask_nulls_data = files.isnull()
    for columns in l1:
        if isinstance(files[columns], object):
            files[columns] = files[columns].astype('str').str.extract("([-+]?\d*\.\d+|[-+]?\d*\\d+)").astype(float)
    mask_nulls_string = files.isnull() & ~mask_nulls_data
    files[mask_nulls_string] = 0`